# expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign Up" to return something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, railstutorial.org

I am working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and I keep getting a failing test that I cannot figure out.

Here is the failure I am getting:

User pages signup page:

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign Up')) }
 expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign Up" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my test file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign Up')) }
  end
end
```

Here is my new.html.erb file:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
```

application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper

    # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
    def full_title(page_title)
      base_title = 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App'
      if page_title.empty?
        base_title
      else
        "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
      end
    end
end
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
    <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Let me know if I should provide more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test is expecting "Sign up", you're passing "Sign Up". Note the difference in capitalization on the word "up".

Comment: Or vice versa, but thats ur problem :)

Comment: I added application_helper.rb. Is that what you were talking about? Also, in the Rails Tutorial screencast, Hartl uses <% %> not <%= %>

Comment: Yeah i noticed why your test was failing, its a typo. Rspec is expecting "Sign Up" ... Your passing "Sign up" in your provide method

Comment: One way to get rid of the typos: `text: /sign up/i`. That is if capitalization isn't important.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Application Layout file (`/app/views/layouts/application.erb.html`) file?

I'm not sure, but it looks as if you may be providing content for the `:title` yield section of that file -- and potentially where that is being substituted into the application layout file may not be what you think.

That is, in the `application.erb.html` file it looks as if you've for a section `yield :title` -- but it may not be rendering as your test thinks it should be.

Can you edit your question and add the application layout (or at least the appropriate section)?

Comment: looks like I had an inconsistency in capitalizing the 'U' in 'Sign Up' when the test was expecting 'Sign up'